# Select positives from a list with Generics

Tags: java, list, generics, numbers

I am pretty new here, so excuse me if you do not understand my question.(Be nice :D)
So basically I have to make a method which select positives "numbers" from a list using Generics.

The base of the method should look like this :

```
public static <T> List<T> selectPositives(List<? extends Number> list) {

        T positiveNumber = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i) > 0) {
                return (List<T>) positiveNumber;
            }
        }
        return (List<T>) positiveNumber;
    }
```

Well obviously this is not working, so I would greatly appreciate any help.
Thanks,
Alma

Comment: You want an upper bound for the generic parameter `T`: `T extends Number`. For details, I recommend reading a tutorial on the topic, e.g. [this one from `oracle.com`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code so that it would return a list of positive numbers.

```
    //public static <T> List<T> selectPositives(List<? extends Number> list) {
    public static <T extends Number> List<T> selectPositives(List<T> list) {
        //T positiveNumber = null;
        List<T> positiveNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).doubleValue() > 0) {
                //return (List<T>) positiveNumber;
                positiveNumbers.add(list.get(i));
            }
        }
        return positiveNumbers;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<Number> list = List.of(-1,-2,1.5, 3,-4,-5, 6);
        System.out.println(selectPositives(list));
    }
```

Output:

```
[1.5, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Stream API, the list of positives may be filtered out of the input:

```java
public static <T extends Number> List<T> selectPositives(List<T> list) {
    return list.stream()
        .filter(x -> x.doubleValue() > 0.0)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Also, `List::removeIf` with inverted condition may be applied to the given input/mutable copy of the input:

```java
public static <T extends Number> List<T> selectPositives(List<T> list) {

    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(list);
    
    result.removeIf(x -> x.doubleValue() <= 0);
    
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

check for absolute value of the number, then compare it to the number without abs. if they match, then it's positive, and if not its negative.

add the elements that match to another list to have all the positive numbers in the list

Comment: i dont understand why i got -2 when this is the logic behind the program

Comment: 1. This is an inefficient way to check if a number is negative, just check if it is less than 0. 2. This question is about Java generics not about the logic of check if a number is less than 0.